# Shrink elements to fit inside div

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a website and I want the server categories to shrink as more get added to fit into their parent div. Currently, the server categories leak out past their parent div, which only covers the search bar:
[Image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jny2w.png)

I've tried a variety of things but here is what I have right now:

The div opening tag:

```
<div class="ui compact selection dropdown prompt search-type multiple" tabindex="0" autocomplete="off">
  <select multiple="" aria-label="Server Version" onfocus="insta_search()" onchange="insta_search()">
```

The categories:

```
<a class="ui label transition visible" data-value="4" style="display: inline-block !important;">
  Factions
  <i class="delete icon"></i>
</a>
```

My CSS:

```
.search-type:not(.active) {
    width: 35%!important;
    display: table-cell;
    flex-flow: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.ui.multiple.dropdown>.label {
    background-color: #6675B0!important;
    color: white;
    
    min-width: 0px;
    min-height: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't abuse with the !important property: the value associated with the !important property will never change.

Second, try to add to the categories's container these values:

display: flex;
flex-shrink: 1